# Jquery slider fix

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made a slider (http://jsfiddle.net/k8f6wp17/) and the problem is in the right button.When you click it , it plays only the #slide2 and #slide3. And one more thing, if you have any suggestions about how I can make it reset. I mean after #slide3 it should play back #slide1. And the JS code:

```
$('.move-slide').click(function() {
        var hiding_image = {  "direction" : "right",  "mode" : "hide"};
        var showing_image = { "direction" : "left", "mode" : "show"};
        var direction = "right";
        // $(this) == current element you clicked
        if($(this).hasClass('glyphicon-chevron-left')) {
            direction = 'left';
            hiding_image = {  "direction" : "left",  "mode" : "hide"};
            showing_image = { "direction" : "right", "mode" : "show"};
        }
           var current_element = $(".slide.active");
 if(direction == 'right' && current_element.next(".slide").length > 0) {
        current_element.next(".slide")
            .effect( "slide", showing_image, 1000)
            .addClass('active')
            .removeClass('inactive');
        current_element.effect( "slide", hiding_image, 1000)
            .removeClass('active');
    } else if(current_element.prev(".slide").length > 0) {
        current_element.prev(".slide")
            .effect( "slide", showing_image, 1000)
            .addClass('active')
            .removeClass('inactive');
        current_element.effect( "slide", hiding_image, 1000)
            .removeClass('active');
    }

});
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't really see where you went wrong. But I did update your code a bit

[new fiddle]
http://jsfiddle.net/pierreduc/k8f6wp17/3/

Hope this helps:

[EDIT]
I've updated the code a bit. Put in a stop() to let the animation stop. Changed the css as well to always hide the slides on inital load.

The problem was that the slide effect removed all classes from the slides. So if you clicked the slide button again, it could not determine the right slide and showed a blank div

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.slide.inactive').hide();
    $('.slide.active').show();

    var slides = $('.slide');
    var active = 0;

    $('.move-slide').click(function () {

        var direction = "right";
        if ($(this).hasClass('glyphicon-chevron-left')) {
            direction = 'left';
        }
        var activeSlide = $(slides[active]);
        var slideToSlide;

        if (direction == 'right') {
            slideTo = active + 1;
            hiding_image = {"direction" : "right", "mode" : "hide"};
            showing_image = {"direction" : "left", "mode" : "show"};

        } else {
            slideTo = active - 1;
            hiding_image = {"direction" : "left", "mode" : "hide"};
            showing_image = {"direction" : "right", "mode" : "show"};
        }

        if (slideTo >= slides.length) {
            slideTo = 0;
        } else if (slideTo < 0) {
            slideTo = slides.length - 1;
        }

        slideToSlide = $(slides[slideTo]);

        slideToSlide.addClass('active').removeClass('inactive');
        activeSlide.removeClass('active').addClass('inactive');

        slideToSlide.stop(true, true).effect("slide", showing_image, 1000);
        activeSlide.stop(true, true).effect("slide", hiding_image, 1000);

        active = slideTo;

    });

});
```

Comment: Looks good but when you click, white screen appears for a secound and then when you slide right , you can see that picture is disappearing.

Comment: I've updated it again. Hope it will work for you now